# node.js - is not a function when exporting

Tags: javascript, node.js, module.exports

I am playing a bit with the modularity of code.
For me it looks fine, even the code editor does not complain and sees methods from `database.js`
However, when I am calling it throws `is not a function` error

`database.js`:

```
function database() {
    function findAll(schemaType, params) {
        return ...
    }

    return { findAll }
}

module.exports = database;
```

And the usage of this module

`model.js`:

```
const database = require('../db/database');

class Model {
    constructor() {
        // .., other logic
        this.findAll = (params) => database.findAll(this.schema, params) //Error pointing to this line
    }
}
```

The error I am getting is pointing directly to the line

> TypeError: `database.findAll` is not a function
> at Movie.Model.findAll (/home/mat/Projects/-task-v3/-task-v3/src/models/model.js:12:45)
> at /home/mat/Projects/-task-v3/-task-v3/src/routes/findAll.js:21:33
> at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/mat/Projects/-task-v3/-task-v3/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
> at next (/home/mat/Projects/-task-v3/-task-v3/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
> at /home/mat/Projects/-task-v3/-task-v3/src/middlewares/query-validator.js:22:9
> at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/mat/Projects/-task-v3/recuitment-task-v3/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
> at next (/home/mat/Projects/-task-v3/-task-v3/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
> at Route.dispatch (/home/mat/Projects/-task-v3/-task-v3/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
> at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/mat/Projects/-task-v3/-task-v3/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
> at /home/mat/Projects/-task-v3/-task-v3/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22

Comment: shouldn't it be `database().findAll()` ?

Comment: Yeah, `database` is the function you exported, that function returns the object with methods. That means you need to run the `database` function to get the object, then you can call `findAll` on it

Comment: or use `module.exports = database()`

Comment: totally missed that. Thanks for reminding me!